# Need to extract last figure after dot in a string like "7.8.9.1.5.1.100"

Tags: c++, string

I need to extract last number after last dot in a C++ string like "7.8.9.1.5.1.100" and store it in an integer??

**Added:**
This string could also be "7.8.9.1.5.1.1" or "7.8.9.1.5.1.0".

I would also like to validate that that its is exactly "7.8.9.1.5.1" before last dot.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`std::string` has a `rfind()` method; that will give you the last `.` From there it's a simple `substr()` to get the string `"100"`.

Comment: and use atoi to get the integer from the string.

Comment: @Benoit Thierry: I'd rather use `stoi` actually, or a `lexical_cast`.

Comment: Did you mean `strtol`? That's the standard alternative to `atoi`.

Answer (score 3):

```
const std::string s("7.8.9.1.5.1.100");
const size_t i = s.find_last_of(".");
if(i != std::string::npos)
{
    int a = boost::lexical_cast<int>(s.substr(i+1).c_str());
}
```

Comment: +1: I prefer `find_last_of` to `rfind` here as it makes it easy to add in new separators e.g. `find_last_of(".,-:")`

Answer (score 1):

Using C++0x regex (or `boost::regex`) check your string against a `basic_regex` constructed from the string literal `"^7\\.8\\.9\\.1\\.5\\.1\\.(?[^.]*\\.)*(\d+)$"`. The capture group `$1` will be useful.

Answer (score 1):

with the updated information, the code below should do the trick.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cstdlib>

int main(void)
{
  std::string base("7.8.9.1.5.1.");
  std::string check("7.8.9.1.5.1.100");
  if (std::equal(base.begin(), base.end(), check.begin())  && check.find('.', base.size()) == std::string::npos)
  {
    std::cout << "val:" << std::atoi(check.c_str() + base.size()) << std::endl;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

EDIT: updated to skip cases where there are more dots after the match, `atoi` would have still parsed and returned the value up to the `.`.

Comment: No, it does not: there could be another `.` further in the string to be checked!

Comment: @Benoit: How so? Did not the OP specify that this was the last dot?

Comment: He wants to ensure that it begins with `7.8.9.1.5.1.` and to get what comes after last dot. Inputs like `7.8.9.1.5.1.42.55b` is not forbidden according to the question, and the answer is “yes it begins with foo, and last portion is `55b`”.

Comment: @Nim: Yes. Then back what I told in 1st comment: you do not check this in your solution. You are checking that the string begins with `7.8.9.1.5.1.` but you do not check that there is no other dot afterwards.

Comment: No input like 55b should not appear in the string.