# Extracting last number after dot in a string like “7.8.9.1.5.1.100”

Tags: c, string

I asked this same question for a solution in C++ but because of some constraints I need the solution in C.

This string could also be "7.8.9.1.5.1.1" or "7.8.9.1.5.1.0".

I would also like to validate that that its is exactly "7.8.9.1.5.1" before last dot.

Added:
These are  separated values. Can we use that to our favor?

Comment: [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4932941/need-to-extract-last-figure-after-dot-in-a-string-like-7-8-9-1-5-1-100)

Comment: probably not a duplicate as that question is about C++

Comment: "Also this will be a tougher thing to crack in C" Why do you think so? Aside from the library function strrchr, it would be trivial to scan back from the end of the string to find the last dot.

Comment: With the correct solution, validation in the way you describe it seems like overkill.  If its a function, I can understand validating the input but why the output?

Comment: I meant relatively only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not tough at all:

Original answer(which is probably what you're interested in):

```
char str[] = "7.8.9.1.5.1.1";
atoi(strrchr(str, '.') + 1);
```

More complete, but not that complete:

```
char str[] = "7.8.9.1.5.1.1";       //example
char *tmp  = NULL;
tmp = strrchr(str, '.');
if(tmp){
  *tmp = '\0';
  if(!strcmp(str, "7.8.9.1.5.1"))     //check for prefix
    return atoi(tmp+1);
}
```

As you can see i also tried to add some sanity checks and to be more safe then this one would have to have more insight into the implied expectations and how the strings are passed around. So to keep this simple i'll stick with this simple case and example of implementation.  :-)

Comment: You can't use ++ like that, you need an lvalue.

Comment: +1. Throw in a check that the string starts with "7.8.9.1.5.1", and you're set. But do `strrchr(str, '.') + 1`, like unwind points out

Comment: @unwind && Øystein lvalue issue fixed.

Comment: @Shinnok: Um, I doubt `strcmp()` will help to check for a prefix.. Have a look at `strncmp()` instead

Comment: shait...hopefully it's fixed now, that's what happens when you try to answer on the run and now i run. :-)

Comment: You really should test your code. I expect that *tmp = '\0' will get a protection violation. Also the initialization of tmp to NULL is pointless. And I know that !strcmp is a common idiom but that doesn't make it any less horrid.

Answer (score 1):

```
int value = -1;
char* lastdot = strrchr(source, '.');
if (lastdot != NULL && lastdot - source == 11 && !strncmp(source, "7.8.9.1.5.1", 11))
    value = atoi(lastdot+1);
```

value will be >= 0 if number was preceded by "7.8.9.1.5.1"

Answer (score 0):

If the language in question is read left to right (like english) then the "last dot" is guaranteed to be the first dot that you encounter if you read the string right to left.
Simplified steps:

1. Find the last dot.  Something like this: `for (int index = strlen(theString); index > 0; --index) { ... details ... }`
2. Read the digits of the number.  Something like this: `for (int index = startingIndex; index < strlen(theString); ++index) { ... details ...}`